# Как реализовать выборку из базы данных MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы одна `user_todo_send`  и `todo_task_send`

у них есть индексы связаны с таблицей `todo` мне нужно получить все данные с таблицы `todo` ид которой есть в двух тех таблицах, вобщем вот запрос

```
SELECT  t.* FROM todo t 

LEFT JOIN user_todo_send uts ON (t.id = uts.id_todo AND uts.id_user  = $id)

LEFT JOIN todo_task_send tts on (t.id = tts.id_todo AND tts.id_user_to =$id)

WHERE ((tts.id_todo IS NOT NULL AND t.confirm = 1) OR (tts.id_todo IS NOT NULL))
```

При этом из одной таблицы нужно получить данные по одному условию а со второй по другому. В итоге получаю результат одинаковый даже если уберу условие `WHERE`

Comment: не совсем ясно, что хотите получить, добавите пример? Можно на http://sqlfiddle.com/
Пока непонятно, почему left join, а не inner, вам же не вся таблица todo нужна, а только пересечение?..

Comment: Возможно, во втором условии uts.id_todo вместо tts.id_todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> LEFT JOIN todo_task_send tts on (t.id = tts.id_todo AND tts.id_user_to =$id)
> WHERE ((tts.id_todo IS NOT NULL AND t.confirm = 1) OR (tts.id_todo IS NOT NULL))
> ```

`t.id = tts.id_todo` - равенство выполнится только если `tts.id_todo` не null. Значит единственны способ получить null в `tts.id_todo` - это за счёт left join. Но условие в where отсеивает все null'ы, значит этот кусок запроса эквивалентен следующему:

```
INNER JOIN todo_task_send tts on (t.id = tts.id_todo AND tts.id_user_to =$id)
WHERE t.confirm = 1
```

Я предполагаю, что это ошибка и на самом деле имелось в виду

```
LEFT JOIN todo_task_send tts on (t.id = tts.id_todo AND tts.id_user_to =$id)
WHERE ((tts.id_todo IS NOT NULL AND t.confirm = 1) OR (tts.id_todo IS NULL))
```

Comment: Я уже решил производить отдельные запросы, но все же спасибо за помощь )

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я вижу, Ваш запрос составлен почти верно.
Почему Вы решили что он выдает не верный результат?
Условие where отсекает строки которых нет ни в одной из 2-х подключаемых таблиц.
Возможно таких условий в Вашей тестовой выборке просто нет, и соответственно разницу Вы и не видете.

Не могли бы Вы показать пример результатов с WHERE и без WHERE, только в SELECT добавьте еще несколько полей, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
SELECT  
    t.*,
    tts.id_todo,
    uts.id_user,
    uts.id_todo,
    tts.id_user_to
FROM
```